# Помогите разобраться с WPF binding

Tags: wpf, binding

В разметке указываю

```
<Window /*xmlns definition*/ 
Width={Binding ElementName=W, Path=Text}>
<Grid>
<TextBox Name="W">
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Но при изменении значения в TextBox, ширина окна не изменяется. Никогда не работал с WPF, Видимо, чего-то не понимаю. Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо указать Mode=TwoWay

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window" Height="300" 
    Width="{Binding ElementName=W, Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay}">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Name="W" Text="300" />
</Grid>
```